# Unity2D - Cannot set SpriteRenderer if Animator attached

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm having trouble setting the sprite property of my SpriteRenderer when there is an Animator component attached, even though the animator is not running an animation. If i disable the animator my code works fine.

Any suggestions?

As I say, the below code works if the Animator is disabled.

```
SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer = gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ();
spriteRenderer.sprite = objectSprite;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "having trouble setting property" is not a problem description. What is actually happening when you try this with the animator enabled?

Comment: The sprite remains unchanged from the original texture. It seems like it's being set, but then perhaps being set again by the animator. I wondered if there were any known caveats when using the 2 together. I don't receive any errors/warnings.

Comment: I'm experiencing same problem right now. Did you come to some solution eventually?

Comment: Instead of resetting the sprite and animation controller i added a few more states that reflect the state of the animation when not running. For example: I created the state 'PlayerFacingUp' and added an individual sprite to the animation.